# DataGrid column Fill to Datagrid size Dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` which is `horizontally stretched` containing `one column`. the problem is the DataGrid gets streached but the column remains same. How can i make it fill the DataGrid. All is done Dynamically, how to do it with code.

```
var datagridDetails = new DataGrid
{
    AutoGenerateColumns = false,
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch
};

var columnDetails = new DataGridTextColumn
{
    Header = "Details",
    CanUserSort = false,
    CanUserResize = false,
    Binding = new Binding("Details"),
    Width = StackPanelContent.ActualWidth/2 - 8 //hacking through it but not working quite well
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XAML this would be:

```
<DataGrid ColumnWidth = "*"/>
```

or

```
<DataGridTextColumn Width="*" />
```

On the actual column definition.

Not sure how to do this in code behind.

Edit:

Found it, it would be:

```
var columnDetails = new DataGridTextColumn
{
    Header = "Details",
    CanUserSort = false,
    CanUserResize = false,
    Binding = new Binding("Details"),
    Width = new DataGridLength(1.0, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star)
```

};

Comment: yes i searched and the XAML way is `"*"` but i don't find the code way

Comment: @ADi I added an edit. Should be what you're looking for.

Comment: maybe bcoz of auto, it on;y give as much width as content. didn't worked

Comment: @ADi Sorry it should be DataGridLengthUnitType.Star

Comment: (edit) my grid was in scroll vier, i removed it and the `.Star` did work, but i need scroolviewr :(

Comment: This wont Work if the `DataGrid` is in `Scrollviewr`

Comment: I'll re structure my Architecture, thanks for your help. It worked well as desired. thanks :)

Comment: Why do you need scrollviewer if you only have 1 column? It has no concept of filling up the space if there is a scrollviewer.

Comment: (y cant i tag u) TylerD87 u r right, i would not need scrollviewer, it was a poor design, but needed bcoz i was dynamically generating controls and design on runtime, so by default i added a scroll to help. but i must not make shortcuts :)